# How to prove the equality

Tags: integration

$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0}\alpha\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{f(x + u)}{\alpha^2 + u^2}du = \pi \frac{\lim_{\alpha\to0}f(x+\alpha) + f(x - \alpha)}{2}$$

Any ideas, please

Comment: Do you now Dirac's delta distribution?

Comment: @tired, now yes, but it don't give me ideas how to start. Do you know some variant how to begin ?